# htaccess file format gives internal server error on some redirects

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a .htaccess file with the following content;

My .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://meervoormamas.nl [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/dossiers/autisme/?$ https://meervoormamas.nl/kind/ontwikkeling/ R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/schoolkind/opvoeding/7\-tips\-om\-uw\-kinderen\-te\-begeleiden\-op\-sociale\-netwerken/?$ https://meervoormamas.nl/kind/opvoeding/7-tips-om-uw-kinderen-te-begeleiden-op-sociale-netwerken/ R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Where the first RewriteRule does work, if I type in https://mamalove.nl it redirects to https://meervoormamas.nl
But with the second RewriteRule(a category in WP) gives an Internal server error, and also with the third RewriteRule (a post).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: An Opening `[` is missing in `R=301,L]` . Is that a typo? See the second last and last line.

Comment: thanks @AmitVerma, that was definitly one of the errors. But still on a line like this I get a 404 error: RewriteRule ^/baby/vaste\-voeding/mijn\-baby\-eet\-slecht/?$ https://meervoormamas.nl/kind/verzorging/tips-voor-moeilijk-etende-dreumesen/ [R=301,L]

Comment: and the destination URL is valid and works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As well as the missing opening `[` that delimits the flags (3rd) argument on the `RewriteRule` directive, as mentioned in comments, in a *directory* (`.htaccess`) context the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* does not start with a slash, so these rules will never match.

Other minor issues:

- You are missing the trailing slash after the domain in the first rule's *substitution* string.
- No need to backslash-escape literal hyphens when used outside of a regex character class (3rd rule).
- The `RewriteBase` directive is not being used here.
- The `<IfModule>` wrapper is not required.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^$ https://meervoormamas.nl/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^dossiers/autisme/?$ https://meervoormamas.nl/kind/ontwikkeling/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^schoolkind/opvoeding/7-tips-om-uw-kinderen-te-begeleiden-op-sociale-netwerken/?$ https://meervoormamas.nl/kind/opvoeding/7-tips-om-uw-kinderen-te-begeleiden-op-sociale-netwerken/ [R=301,L]
```

Since you appear to be redirecting to a *similar* URL-path in the 3rd rule, this can be "simplified" by avoiding repetition. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^school(kind/opvoeding/7-tips-om-uw-kinderen-te-begeleiden-op-sociale-netwerken)/?$ https://meervoormamas.nl/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

`$1` is a backreference that contains everything in the captured group in the preceding *pattern*. It basically just removes the "school" prefix and ensures the redirected URL ends in a trailing slash.

If these rules are being used on an existing WordPress site then these directives must go at the top of the `.htaccess` file, *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` section.